# Count how many rows and columns are in a mysql datatable

Tags: mysql

I can't believe this hasn't been asked yet, but how do I get the shape of a datatable in a mysql database?

Eg. if I have a data table of 4 rows and two columns, I'd see something to that effect reported out. Perhaps [4,2] or something similar.

Comment: It's not that it has not been asked, it's more like you weren't able to find the right way to explain it to find the answer, or the contrary, the one who posted a similar question didn't rephrase it as you did :)

Comment: Querying information_schema is super slow.  "desc table;" and counting with your fingers is faster.  Not that nobody's asked it; just, that's not how information_schema is designed to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the number of rows, a simple count query will do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows FROM yourTable;
```

For the number of columns, we need to do a bit more work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_columns
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourdatabasename' 
AND TABLE_NAME = 'yourTable';
```

You could combine these into a single query if you wanted, or even write a stored procedure.  By the way, I can't even think of the last time I needed to know the *number* of columns in a MySQL table.  Most of the time, you would know beforehand which columns you wanted to access, and so you would not need a numerical count.  The number of rows is another story, and often you might want to know this.

Comment: Thanks Tim. That's right, this is after accessing a table and using it for some data science work - I'm writing up a report on what I used and thought it'd be helpful to have a quick way to grab the original size of the raw data. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps off topic, but if you're loading this data into something like R or MATLAB, then it might be easier to answer this question in those packages.

Comment: Sure, I'm familiar with the python and R way to do it; this data is stored in mysql and too massive to pull the entire set - I was already working with a subset.

Comment: I've always preferred count() to info_schema.  select count() here responded with "1 row in set (0.00 sec)", querying the information_schema, though, gave me: "1 row in set (0.83 sec)."

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL use the following query in your database :

```
SELECT
    table_schema,
    table_name,
    data_length,
    index_length
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tableName';
```

They are stored in the information schema which keeps details of all the tables created.

Comment: I just tested this.  select count() gave me 10,641 rows, but this query gave data_length as a 3,600,668, and index_length as 415,744.  Select Count(*) took 0.00 seconds; this query took 0.83 seconds.  Besides speed problems, is some type of division needed now?  (is index_length not what you think?)